# changing data fetched from server in json format in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

ive got a script in php which fetched data from server, but i want to encode it in json format.

```
 <?php
 // attempt a connection
 $dbh = pg_connect("host=10.22.35.11 dbname=iwmp_dev2 user=postgres "); 

 if (!$dbh) {
   die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
      }       

   // execute query
  //$sql = $_POST['pLat'];
  $sql = "SELECT officer_name FROM iwmp_officer";

  $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
 if (!$result) {
 die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
  }       
 $array = array();
 while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $i++;
     $comm = implode(",",$row);
    echo json_encode($comm); 
   }

  // free memory
  pg_free_result($result);       

   // close connection
   pg_close($dbh);
   ?>
```

but my ouptput is coming in format

> "V. M. ARORA""Dr. C. P. REDDY""ARTI CHOWDHARY""JAGDISH SINGH" 
>   also when using implode func on *pgsql_fetch_assoc*, no **","**(coma's) are coming.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo json_encode($row); 
}
```

Comment: PLEASE HELP IN HOW TO ACCESS THIS JSON_ENCODED DATA IN ANDROID. THAN YOU,COZ WHEN I AM USING UR PHP VERSION MY ANDROID APP IS CRASHING,. PLUS DEGUGGER IS ALSO NOT SHOWING EXCEPTION AS "NULL" :p I CANT UNDERSTAND A THING BRO.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're doing it in wrong way. Try to do like below.

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row; 
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: i wanna use this encoded json array in android app,i am able to do dis, but i am getting all the "{}" (curly brackets) in dat.

Comment: [{"officer_name":"V. M. ARORA"},{"officer_name":"Dr. C. P. REDDY"},{"officer_name":"ARTI CHOWDHARY"},{"officer_name":"JAGDISH SINGH"}]

Comment: my php output, i only want the names in my array ..in android, but its cuming.. {"officer_name":"V.M.ARORA"}

Comment: Your string is totally fine. So there might be issue in calling or passing this data to your android app.

Comment: you mean , that my php output is perfectly fine, its jsonEncoded, ryt? now problem is in when i am calling it.... can u post any example if possible to see how to post these things exaclty. thank you sir

Comment: one more thing, this officer_name is my column name, which is cuming with all values, in this row[] array, how can i ditch this.

Comment: Really not getting you. You need to post your desire output so that we can have a better idea?

Comment: sir i only want "V.M.ARORA"..instead of {"officer_name":"V.M.ARORA"} and parsing is not the problem coz i am first taking the whole json_encoded(row) in string and then creating a new json array  and casting this row String in dat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29119/discussion-between-rikesh-and-yug)

Comment: @ Rikesh, should i use a normal string manipulation , to get just names out of this whole {"officer_name":"V.M.ARORA"}.. its not  a valid thing thou, is their another way..?

Comment: @yug Try `$rows[] = array_values($row);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implode the `$row`. Try replacing your while loop with below code

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo json_encode($row); 
}
```

Comment: PLEASE HELP IN HOW TO ACCESS THIS JSON_ENCODED DATA IN ANDROID. THAN YOU,COZ WHEN I AM USING UR PHP VERSION MY ANDROID APP IS CRASHING,. PLUS DEGUGGER IS ALSO NOT SHOWING EXCEPTION AS "NULL" :p I CANT UNDERSTAND A THING BRO.

Comment: PLEASE HELP IN HOW TO ACCESS THIS JSON_ENCODED DATA IN ANDROID. THAN YOU,COZ WHEN I AM USING UR PHP VERSION MY ANDROID APP IS CRASHING,. PLUS DEGUGGER IS ALSO NOT SHOWING EXCEPTION AS "NULL" :p I CANT UNDERSTAND A THING BRO.